# ¿Cómo cambiar la ruta home en react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo una app en react con react-router en la cual necesito que al entrar a la ruta **localhost:3000** automaticamente se redireccione a **localhost:3000/balance**

En otra palabras quiero que **localhost:3000/balance** sea el nuevo home de la app.

Aquí el código:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
      <Switch>
        {/* <Route exact path="/">
          <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>
        </Route> */}
        <Route exact path="/balance">
          <Sales></Sales>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/productos">
          <Products></Products>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/productos/crear">
          <ProductsCreate></ProductsCreate>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/ventas/crear">
          <SalesCreate></SalesCreate>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/clientes">
          <Clients />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/clientes/crear">
          <ClientsCreate />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/proveedores">
          <Providers />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/proveedores/crear">
          <ProvidersCreate />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*">
          <h1>404</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar el componente `Redirect` de `react-router` asi podras redireccionar a la ruta que deseas.

Puedes agregarlo dentro del componente `Route` de home para que haga la redireccion automatica.

```js
<Route exact path="/">
  <Redirect to="/balance" />
</Route>
```

Espero que te ayude, saludos.